# Extend Windows 7 partition to use free space before it

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, mbr, disk-management

I have some unallocated space before my Windows 7 partition.

[image: Unallocated space before Windows 7 partition]

Can I move the Windows 7 partition so that the free space is after it instead than before it, and then extend the partition to use all of the currently unallocated space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, however, I doubt that you can using the default disk management tool.

The easiest thing you can do is to load up [Gparted live cd (free)](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) and then you should be able to move and extend the partition with no problem.

Comment: @August: Don't forget to back up your data before doing this.

Comment: Is Gparted able to work with MBR partitions, or will it convert the MBR to GPT?

Comment: @August Lilleaas - I use Gparted a lot on MBR drives - it can handle it well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free windows partition program that also might do the job. There is another one that I used recently that worked, but I don't remember (it's on my home computer). The changes made will require windows to shutdown, then repartition, then restart.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/download.html

I'm not sure if this is the software I used or not, but I assume you can find out quickly whether or not it is capable

Comment: btw, I'm curious why your partition is so far out. Is that to put the OS on the outer bands of your harddrive to improve performance? or is this because you started with a different OS, then dual booted, then decided to stick with Win7... interesting

Comment: I have a similar scheme - it my case, it was because I stated with XP, used the Win7 resize option when installing Win7, and then tried to add some additional space to the win7 installation by shrinking the XP partition.

Comment: I've tried this program, it failed and destroyed the target partition. Don't use it.