# Extend Windows 7 partition to the left using remote access

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, remote-desktop

I have read the normal answers like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/134994/extend-windows-7-partition-to-use-free-space-before-it).

However, they require GParted or other software requiring a reboot.

Suppose I only have access to the machine in question using Remote Desktop or Teamviewer. How can I do the resize?

My current layout:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend a non-system disk left or right without rebooting Windows 7, using the free [Minitool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/).